# Keep getting nil when trying to get the phone number

Tags: ios, swift

I'm saving a phone number as a string right now and it is using json object.

```
{ 
  userFirstName: 'Jamie',
  phone: '019-443 4444',
 }
```

I saved the json object into a variable called `phoneNumber`

```
var phoneNumber: String?
```

So I tried to print out the phone number and it works

```
@IBAction func calledPassenger(_ sender: MyButton) {
       if let phone = phoneNumber {
           print(phone) 
       }
}
```

Result on the xcode console is `019-443 4444`

When I tried to do with the NSURL i got unexpected nil

```
 @IBAction func calledPassenger(_ sender: MyButton) {

        if let phone = phoneNumber {
            if let phoneCallURL:URL = URL(string:"tel://\(phone)") {
                let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
                if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
                    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                        application.open(phoneCallURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                    } else {
                        // Fallback on earlier versions
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What is the problem right now?

Comment: how do you saved `phoneNumber`

Comment: `self.phoneNumber = phone` the `phone` is a json object

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the "-" character.
Also if you want a default format ( without spaces) use URL(string:"telprompt://" + phone.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: ""))